# Strange behaviour with nltk sentence tokenizer and special characters

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, sentence

I get some strange behavior when using the `sent_tokenizer` for German text.

Example Code:

```
sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
for sent in sent_tokenizer.tokenize("Super Qualität. Tolles Teil.")
      print sent
```

This fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
for sent in sent_tokenize("Super Qualität. Tolles Teil."):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 82, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1270, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1318, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1309, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1348, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 354, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1324, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1369, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1504, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 354, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 621, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 586, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

whereas:

```
  sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
  for sent in sent_tokenizer.tokenize("Super Qualität des Produktes. Tolles Teil.")
      print sent
```

works perfectly

Comment: Are you missing the "r" at the end of the function name? "`for sent in sent_tokenize("Super Qualität. Tolles Teil."):`"

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl just a typo in the question :-). This wasn't the problem.

Comment: The problem is in sentences with last word containing non ASCII chars. But I don't know the reason. If you use this way u"Super Qualität. Tolles Teil." works.

Comment: What is the encoding of text? If you pass encoding in `load` may works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on the [nltk homepage](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

> Caution: when tokenizing a Unicode string, make sure you are not using
>   an encoded version of the string (it may be necessary to decode it
>   first, e.g. with s.decode("utf8").

So

```
text = "Super Qualität. Tolles Teil."
sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
for sent in sent_tokenizer.tokenize(text.decode('utf8')):
      print sent
```

works like a charm.